# Bin packing, Decision vs Optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, bin-packing

For an assignment I have been given the bin packing problem and asked to show how you can solve the decision version of the problem from the optimization version and vice versa. I understand that to solve the decision version you simply take the number of bins used in the optimization version and compare it to the max number of bins specified but how can I use the decision version to solve the optimization version?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the decision version to solve the optimization version by observing that if `N` bins is sufficient, then `K > N` bins will also be sufficient.

Start with a single bin, and run the decision version on it. If the answer is `true`, you are done; otherwise, keep doubling the number of bins until you hit a `true`. Let's say that you get an answer of `true` when you try `N = 2 ^ k`. Then you can run a binary search between `M = 2^(k-1)` and `N`, inclusive, to find the exact solution to the optimization problem (both `N` and `k` come from the previous step).

Consider this example: let's say the optimal solution is 14. You could then try the following sequence of decision problem to find the answer:

- 1 --> `false`
- 2 --> `false` (doubled 1)
- 4 --> `false` (doubled 2)
- 8 --> `false` (doubled 4)
- 16 --> `true` (doubled 8; we've got a `true`, so proceed to the binary search)
- 12 --> `false` (midpoint between 8 and 16)
- 14 --> `true` (midpoint between 12 and 16)
- 13 --> `false` (midpoint between 12 and 14)

In general, the answer can be found in logarithmic time (i.e. in Log<sub>2</sub>(Answer)).

Once you know the number of bins `N` required to package `X` objects, run a bipartite matching algorithm between the items on one side and the `N` bins on the other side. Assuming that the decision problem is solved correctly, such bipartite matching must exist, [and can be found in polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Matching).

Comment: I can see where you're going with this, that will result in the right number of bins. But I don't see how it tells which item goes in each bin?

Comment: If the size n decision problem takes `f(n)` steps, then the finding the size takes `sum_{n \in S}f(n)` steps, where S is the `O(log(N))` sized set of problem sizes that have to be tested.

Comment: The last paragraph of this is completely wrong. The Bin-Packing decision problem is NP-Complete, which means the search problem is NP-Hard. If your algorithm were correct, P would have to equal NP, because the Search variant of the Bin-Packing problem could be solved in polynomial time by the following algorithm: "For a specific number of bins $k$, run a bipartite matching algorithm from the items to the bins. If the matching returned is valid, output the assignment, otherwise, output that the problem has no solution." For your algorithm to work, so does this one. And it doesn't.

Comment: @codetaku What does NP-hardness/NP-completeness have to do with my answer? The OP wants to know how to solve bin packing optimization problem, **assuming that he already has a solution to a decision problem**. Nothing else is there.

Comment: @codetaku To elaborate on the above comment, the solution that he plugs into the algorithm that I describe can take a long time to compute. I assume that he gives me a function that solves the decision problem - as if by magic. My job is to construct an optimization solution that uses that magic algorithm as a building block. If that algorithm happens to be NP-Complete, my algorithm will take a very long time.

Comment: @codetaku is right. The problem of determining the actual packing solution cannot be transformed into a polynomially solvable bipartite matching problem. This part of your answer is incorrect. Obtaining an actual feasible packing solution for a fixed number of bins is at least as hard as deciding that a feasible solution exists. Because the decision problem is already NP-complete, there cannot be an algorithm in P that solves the former.

Comment: @Andreas Please read the comment that I wrote for codetaku. I am not suggesting that bin packing decision problem could be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Then you should elaborate on the purpose of the bipartite matching algorithm that you suggest in your edit as "Added the final step to reach an optimization solution." To the best of my knowledge the bipartite matching is irrelevant to the question and does not address the part of the question that asks for a packing solution (which item goes into which bin). Reducing bin packing to bipartite matching would lead to an iterative algorithm that is neither optimal nor does it come with the guarantee of finding a feasible solution even if it exists. Please prove me wrong.